# How to investigate cluster quality?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I have been experimenting with the K-means clustering algorithm.
I have a dataset of movie reviews with which i am fiddling, trying to cluster them using features that i manually(well, programmatically) defined.
I came to understand that it's impossible to know in advance the value of k to use before Clustering, and I am not sure myself the number of clusters I would like to have. I figured i could just obtain the clusters and manually observe the previously unobserved similarity of the entities in the same cluster.

My questions are the following:

1. Will the elements of the same cluster really be related ?
2. Will the "quality" of the clustering be the same in every cluster ? How do I verify it ?

Answer (score 0):

about your first question , it's not really a good question bro , because our data don't have label , we use clustering algorithm to label it ( you know after clustering we have cluster 1,2,... or a,b,c or what ever label you want to assign)

and your second question:

after clustering your data there is some measure that you can use to find out how good you perform your clustering take look at this

```
  http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~kumar/dmbook/dmslides/
```

or the simple way to analyze your result is calculate entropy measure for each cluster the less the entropy measure is the better your result is ( you get the best entropy if the number of your cluster is equal to number of your data points , think about it )

look at it from the information theory perspective , the entropy measure is represent how much information is store in the data points that you are looking at (the same the data the less they can carry information , think about the DC <1> signal it's always on <(lowest entropy)> , it's the only thing we can get from it, now think about this signal<01011110... > the more it can differ ,the more information you can get from it <(higher entropy)>...  ) back to business , now after clustering we want to our data points in each cluster to be similar , so the more similar our data points in each cluster is the less the entropy measure is .
good luck bro !